# Evaluate: $I(x)=\int_0^x\ t^{a}\ (\sin\ t)^{b} dt $

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, trigonometric-integrals

I would calculate (by using a series of functions probably) this integral:

$$I(x)=\int_0^x\ t^{a}\ (\sin\ t)^{b} dt $$

where $$ x\in\ [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \ \ \ \ \| \ \ \  a,b \in\mathbb{N}$$

Using the hypergeometric functions:

$$I(x)=\int_0^x\  t^{a+1}\   (\ _0F_1(\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{4}t^2)\ )^b \ dt$$

But in this way I do not think it is possible to continue integration

Thanks in advance

Comment: Another scheme is integration by parts to reduce the exponents, together with double angle formulas.

Comment: Are you forced to use HyperGeometric functions?

Comment: The integration by parts approach seems straightforward.

Comment: because they are very general functions that can easily represent many other special features (for example Legendre polynomials, Bessel series and many others)

Comment: The problem is that "a" and "b" are very large numbers, in the order of 50-70